# Incrustar video que vuelva al comienzo al terminar y se quede parado

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, video

Tengo la duda de como incrustar un video en WP que al finalizar vuelva a la imagen de comienzo pero que no se reproduzca de nuevo si no damos a play otra vez.

No es un video en bucle infinito sino uno que vuelva al estado inicial sin recargar la página.

A ver si entre todos lo resolvemos.

Comment: Puedes compartir que has intentado?

Comment: Se me ocurre como idea poner el video per se en la web y que hacerte un script en JS que controle con un setTimeOut o setInterval la duración concreta del video y lo detenga.